# How can I boot my bootsector files with qemu?

Tags: assembly, x86-64, qemu, x86-emulation

I'm doing some experimenting with (very basic) OS development in order to teach myself something about machine language and x86 assembly.

I have lib-virt / qemu installed on my system. (Debian 11)

However I am struggling to find a convenient way to boot my output files.

I have assembled some assembly code using `nasm bootsector.asm -f bin -o bootsector.bin`.

Initially I tried running this command:

```
qemu bootsector.bin
```

however I obtained the error `command not found`. I believe this is because (for whatever reason, I don't know exactly) the command supplied with my package manager is actually this:

```
qemu-system-x86_64 bootsector.bin
```

however this produces this output, which is not what I would expect

```
WARNING: Image format was not specified for 'bootsector.bin' and probing guessed raw.
     Automatically detecting the format is dangerous for raw images, write operations on block 0 will be restricted.
     Specify the 'raw' format explicitly to remove the restrictions.
VNC server running on ::1:5900
```

I would have expected a graphical window to pop up showing the output of the emulated boot process. However apparently instead a VNC server is being launched instead.

Some searching around online indicated that `-display sdl` or `-display gtk` might be required to launch the display. (However I don't recall this being required in versions of qemu from a few years back.)

Neither of these switches work, both print

```
Display `gtk`/`sdl` is not avaiable.
```

I couldn't find a solution to this. I believe qemu packages for Debian are not built with either gtk or sdl support. I don't know exactly why this is.

Therefore I tried an alternative method, which is to create a virtual machine using `virt-manager` and assign my bootsector as the single storage device.

This works, but only once. After launching the vm, the bootsector file is changed ownership and group to `libvirt`. This then prevents my makefile from over-writing it, as it is a write protected file.

At this point I am out of ideas. I assume that there must be a fair number of SO users who play around with OS development or even do it full time as a career. How do I fix the problems I have with qemu or alternatively what else can I do to speed up my development process. All I want to do is to be able to start an emulator from the command line and boot my experimental boot sectors.

Comment: Try installing _qemu-system-gui_. Or you can of course just connect with your favorite vnc viewer.

Comment: @Jester Perfect, thanks that's essentially solved my problem. Strangly enough I couldn't find that info via searching - mostly just stuff about the packages not being compiled to include this.

Comment: Cross-site [duplicate](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1309029/qemu-display-gtk-and-display-sdl-not-available-ubuntu-20-04-1-lts)

Answer (score 0):

try with -nographic -serial mon:stdio